# Copy files from Amazon EC2 to an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, network-traffic

I would like to copy files from  my Amazon EC2 instance to an Amazon S3 bucket.  didn't open the port,protocol of EC2 security group. Still I am able to copy file from EC2 to Amazon S3, how does that happens? on which port, protocol does traffic flow?

Comment: The default security group is to allow all outbound traffic to all IPs, including S3 which operates on HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks, if I remove the all outbound ports, can't ec2 reach the S3?, If I want to reach only s3, what is the cidr I need to open in outbound?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the security group allows all outbound traffic which includes the s3 traffic(HTTPS) as well.
You can disable this, but by doing this you are disabling all outbound HTTPS connections and your machine won't be able to communicate even for software/os update as well.

I understood that you are trying to find the CIDR for S3 service. For that you can use the following command

```
curl https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json | jq -r '.prefixes[] | select(.service=="S3") | .ip_prefix'
```

this will list all the IPv4 addresses used by AWS s3.